# How to edit span text with selenium or robot and save it

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have an application where to enter/change values it uses monaco-editor, and values are inside spans, Manually I go and change it, and save it, it gets saved, but when doing with selenium/robotframework via innerText change, it does changes on UI, but as soon as it saves it, it re-sets its value and not saving.

Tried this

```
self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerHTML = "{}";'.format(value), elem)
```

but it shows value changed, but doesn't save it.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You should try to simulate user actions, like with `Press Keys`.

Comment: It doesn't support press keys, its innerText, which needs to be changed and saved

Comment: Almost looks like the end-user is going to input text with that technique. Selenium (SeleniumLibrary) reproduces user behavior, if that is not possible, you should use another testing framework. I am not saying it is not possible, only that I don't see doing that with RobotFramework. Do you know any public site using the same component, so we can try to do experiments?

Comment: Please check - https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/ - it has example of editor

only difference I need to save the changed value, in above it doesn't have any save option, and changing text can be achieved by the method i have mentioned.

Comment: It's not specific to robotframework, even with selenium(python) same behaviour can be seen. 
if it can be done by python-selenium, then i can have that in a lib and use in robot test.